# Standard way of getting information about element that triggered a particular event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, dom-events

If the HTML is like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="link">Click Me</a>
```

and I set the `eventHandler` for `click` as

```
ele.addEventListener('click', clickme, false);
```

What's the pretty standard way of getting the value of `ele` in handler.

I succeed getting the value of `ele` in chrome by: (working example - http://jsfiddle.net/hy5Pz/4/ )

```
function clickme(e){
  var ele = e.toElement;
  ele.innerText = "I got clicked"; 
}
```

and in Firefox by: (working example - http://jsfiddle.net/hy5Pz/3/ )

```
function clickme(e){
  var ele = e.rangeParent;
  ele.data="I got clicked";
}
```

I am new to JavaScript so I want to know if there is a pretty standard cross-useragent way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe

```
var ele = e.currentTarget || e.srcElement;
```

Will work in most browsers. It basically tries to use `e.target` first, and if that's not found, use `e.srcElement` instead. `e.target` is used in good browsers, `e.srcElement` in IE.

Comment: +1; In addition `innerText` isn't entirely cross browser friendly. (Firefox versions less than 4 don't recognize it).

Comment: @Xeon06 Thanks for your answer but `e.target` & `e.srcElement` gives the `href` value. http://jsfiddle.net/hy5Pz/5/

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi no it doesn't. It gives you the element. Using `alert` will only show you the `href` on an anchor. Don't use `alert`. http://jsfiddle.net/hy5Pz/7/

Comment: @AbhijeetRastogi, actually, it returns the DOM node, but `alert` automatically calls `toString` which turns a link into the `href` value. You should use `console.log` instead of alert.

Comment: @Xeon06 Lesson learned to never used `alert()` for checking values. Thanks.

Comment: This is actually not quite right.  `e.target` will be the innermost element the event fired on, not the one the event listener is on.  For the latter, you want `e.currentTarget`.

Comment: @BorisZbarsky, in the case of a link, `e.currentTarget` gives my `null`. Should we be ORing it too?

Comment: @Xeon06 In which browser?  In browsers in which `e.currentTarget` is supported, it should just work in all cases.  To work cross-browser, you will need to do some sort of ORing....

Comment: @BorisZbarsky ah, it seems it only happens when attaching the event to the `$0` object (currently inspected element in Chrome). Guess that makes sense. I've edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

if you're using `addEventListener`, `this` will be the element that the event was originally bound on. `e.target` will be the element that triggered the event. If you changed the markup to:

```
<a href="#" id="link">
  <span>Click Me</span>
</a>
```

`e.target` would be the `span`, rather than the `a` element.

Comment: I have read that `#` should not be used for `href`. That's the reason I used `javascript:void(0)` but I observed you using `#`. What's your say on this?

Comment: I would love to explain the advantages and disadvantages between `href="#"`, `href="javascript:void(0)"`, `<a>` (no `[href]`) and `href="/path/to/some/page"`, but unfortunately I don't have the time currently, and It certainly wont fit in a comment box. Long story short, it wont make a significant difference if you remember to call `e.preventDefault()` in your event handler (or `return false;`). In the end it's more important to choose the correct [WAI-ARIA role](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#widget_roles). `<a href="#" role="button" id="link">` might be more appropriate in this case.